# Read the files in the ‘download’ folder (of Chromebook) and USB drive (of Chromebook) from a ‘Chrome App’ without user intervention

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, fileapi, chromebook

I am currently developing a ‘Chrome App’ which will be used only by the Chromebooks. 
Here, I’ve a business requirement to read the files in the ‘download’ folder (of Chromebook) and USB drive (of Chromebook) from the ‘Chrome App’ without user intervention.

***Following are the challenges that I encounter:***

- While using HTML5 FileSystem API, there is a sandbox restriction
  (i.e., to read and write files without user intervention). Because of
  this, the ‘Download folder’ (of Chromebook) and USB drive are not
  accessible.
- While using the chrome.fileSystem API, the files in the
  ‘download’ folder and ‘USB’ are accessible – however, a dialog
  prompts the user to select the folder. This solution wouldn’t work
  for me – as my business requirement is to  read the files in the
  ‘Download folder’ (of Chromebook) and USB drive from a ‘chrome app’
  without user intervention.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The user action requirement is intentional and cannot be bypassed.

Comment: A Kiosk app can get access to USB drives without explicit authorization